# Ruby On Rails libyaml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I'm running rails version 3.2.8 and ruby version 1.9.3-p286 on Linux

```
user1@company.com [~/rails_apps/myapp]# rails -v
Rails 3.2.8
user1@company.com [~/rails_apps/myapp]# ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p286 (2012-10-12 revision 37165) [x86_64-linux]
user1@company.com [~/rails_apps/myapp]#
```

I can generate a migration but I cannot run it. I keep getting the following error message

```
user1@company.com [~/rails_apps/myapp]# rake db:migrate
/home3/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:56:in `<top (required)>':
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
/home3/user1/ruby/gems/gems/json-1.7.5/lib/json/common.rb:67: [BUG] unknown type 0x22 (0xc given)
ruby 1.9.3p286 (2012-10-12 revision 37165) [x86_64-linux]
<snip>
```

then a lot of debug info

```
[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Aborted
user1@company.com [~/rails_apps/myapp]#
```

I installed libyaml

```
rvm pkg install libyaml
```

then reinstalled ruby

```
rvm reinstall ruby-1.9.3-p286
```

but that did not help.

Any other ideas why I keep getting this error message?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need the **libtool** package installed on your system, otherwise **libyaml** won't compile. For Ubuntu try:

`sudo apt-get install libtool

rvm pkg install libyaml

rvm pkg install libyaml-dev

rvm reinstall 1.9.3`

Also you can simply use your distro's package manager to install the library instead of rvm. For Ubuntu:

`sudo apt-get install libyaml libyaml-dev`

Comment: Thanks svilenv for your response. I tried to install libtool and it gave me another error
user1company@company.com [~]# yum instll libtool
CRITICAL:yum.cli:Config Error: Error accessing file for config file:///etc/yum.conf
user1@company.com [~]#

Answer (score 0):

You have two distinct issues here, a warning produced by Yaml followed by an error from the JSON gem.

The warning is:

```
/home3/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:56:in `<top (required)>':
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
```

This isn’t necessarily a problem, your Ruby installation will fall back to using the older Syck Yaml library. Syck has been removed from Ruby 2 so you’ll need to address it eventually, but it’s not the major problem at the moment.

Immediately after the Yaml warning you get this:

```
/home3/user1/ruby/gems/gems/json-1.7.5/lib/json/common.rb:67: [BUG] unknown type 0x22 (0xc given)
ruby 1.9.3p286 (2012-10-12 revision 37165) [x86_64-linux]
```

which is an error coming from the JSON gem. The JSON gem uses native extensions, and I think this error comes from using a gem installed with an earlier version of Ruby with a later version. Try reinstalling your gems (particularly `json`) to fix this.

Comment: Thanks matt. I'd appreciate if you can guide me a bit more how to re-install the gems and json? I'm rather a beginner in this arena. Thanks

Comment: I tried to reinstall gems, but it gave me a similar error message user1@company.com [~]# gem update --system
/home3/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:56:in `<top (required)>':
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
Latest version currently installed. Aborting.
user1@company.com [~]#

Comment: I also installed libyaml following the instruction here http://pyyaml.org/wiki/LibYAML but still no luck

Comment: @rh4games You seem to be loading gems from an odd path (`/home3/user1/ruby/gems`) which isn’t in your rvm directory or your app directory, so I don’t really know the best way for you to upgrade. Have you recently updated Ruby to 1.9.3? It looks like you may have some stuff left around that you need to clean up. You could just try `gem uninstall json` followed by `gem install json`.

Comment: Thanks matt for the response. Yes, I recently upgraded to 1.9.3. I wrk in a hosted environment (BlueHost) , not on a standalone machine, and that's the path they gave me. I tried gem unistall json then gem install json, but still no luck.